# Rename interval partitioning system generated partition names

Tags: partitioning, oracle-11g

I have an existing table which I partitioned (interval partitioning on a daily basis) using `dbms_redefnition`.

```
PARTITION BY RANGE ("TIME_ID") INTERVAL (NUMTODSINTERVAL(1,'DAY')) 
(PARTITION "p1_1"  VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE(' 01-jan-2013','DD-MON-YYYY' )))
```

This gives me a new system generated partition names every day (like `SYS41`, `SYS42`, ...).

I have two questions:

1. I want a script which should run daily and change this system generated name to custom name (like "01-jan-2013" and so on for every date). This script should be run daily through `dbms_scheduler`. I have a script which give me the name of latest created partition.

   ```
   SELECT PARTITION_NAME FROM DBA_TAB_PARTITIONS A
   WHERE PARTITION_POSITION = (
     SELECT MAX(PARTITION_POSITION) 
     FROM USER_TAB_PARTITIONS B
     WHERE A.TABLE_NAME = B.TABLE_NAME
       AND B.TABLE_NAME = 'IPART'
   );
   ```

   This may help you to give the answer.
2. I want a script which should delete the old partitions (say 3 months) automatically. This should also run daily. And that 3 months time should be configurable.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Daily partitions? How many billion rows are you dealing with?

Comment: Hi Phil, I am not sure how many rows are there in the client side. But, It will cross billion for sure. I wanted a script which will run every 24 hours and rename the newly created system partition because of interval partitioning. And another script which will delete 3 months old partitions daily. This will be running every 24 hours. I also have some global indexes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a trick you can use, at least for date-range partitions: the `HIGH_VALUE` field in `user_tab_partitions` is a valid date expression. If you "eval" that, you'll get a date object for the cutoff point for that partition. You can then use that to build your partition name from.

Sample PL/SQL to try out (generates a string from the `high_value` column):

```
declare
  hv varchar2(9);
begin
  for x in (select partition_name, high_value
              from user_tab_partitions
              where table_name = 'FOO' and partition_name not like 'PART_%')
  loop
    execute immediate 'select to_char('||x.high_value||'-1,''YYYYMMDD'') from dual' into hv;
    dbms_output.put_line('alter table foo rename partition '||x.partition_name
                       ||' to PART_'||hv);
  end loop;
end;
/
```

(Replace the `put_line` with `execute immediate` once you've verified that it actually does what you want. The `-1` in the date select is to make it more "human friendly", i.e. partition name to match the date it contains.)

As for dropping old partitions, you can use the same trick. Same type of loop to get a date object for each partition, and generate an `alter table ... drop partition ...` statement for the partitions you don't want to keep.

Simplistic example where you would drop partitions older than 10 days (be vary wary of off-by-one errors, there probably is one below):

```
declare
  dt date;
begin
  for x in (select partition_name, high_value
              from user_tab_partitions
              where table_name = 'FOO')
  loop
    execute immediate 'select '||x.high_value||' from dual' into dt;
    if dt < sysdate - 10 then
      dbms_output.put_line('to drop: '||x.partition_name);
    end if;
  end loop;
end;
/
```

You're then left with taking care of index maintenance if necessary.

Comment: Thank you Mat for your answer. I just have one doubt in the renaming part. Is that a daily script. Or, that is like you can run once in a month, and it will change all the system generated partition names.

Comment: Look at the last part of the `where` clause. It renames all partitions that don't match the scheme. You could change that so that it renames all partitions that match the system-generated scheme. (You could run that every hour if you fell like it, or every year.)

Comment: One more query, going through the whole table will cause any performance issue as my table is huge and is live(insertions keep happening all the time) even when you will be partitioning the table. I have some global indexes, will that cause a problem?

Comment: Dropping partitions without the appropriate `update indexes` clause will invalidate all global indexes. That's potentially a big problem if your table is huge.  It might actually prevent you from dropping them during normal operations and restrict you to week-ends (if that's acceptable). (The rename part doesn't touch the table data and doesn't invalidate indexes.)

Comment: Can you give me script to update indexes while dropping the partitions. Unfortunately my table is huge and this drop partition script should run every 24 hours and the table is live as well. What can be done for this??

Comment: Then you should probably use the appropriate `update indexes` clause in your drop partition statement rather than rebuild all the global indexes. (Aside, there are lots of "rebuild unusable indexes" scripts out there, give it a quick search.)

Comment: My table stops me from renaming the partitions when the table is live..I get the following error                                                      .Error report:
ORA-00054: resource busy and acquire with NOWAIT specified or timeout expired
ORA-06512: at line 9
00054. 00000 -  "resource busy and acquire with NOWAIT specified"
*Cause:    Resource interested is busy.
*Action:   Retry if necessary.

Comment: @Rajesh try adding a `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SESSION SET DDL_LOCK_TIMEOUT = 180';` to set the lock wait time.